# Quiero crear una condicion con un bucle foreach y agregar la respuesta a una tabla ya echa, el problema no se como incluirlo a la tabla

Tags: php, html, php7

```
<?php 

$datospersonas = array(
    "persona_1" => array(
        "Nombre" => "Camila",
        "Direccion" => "Cra. 45 # 45 - 56",
        "Telefono" => "236-598-4785",
        "Fecha de Cumpleaños" => "23/12/1997",
        "Color Favorito" => "Naranga"
    ),
    "persona_2" => array(
        "Nombre" => "Manuel",
        "Direccion" => "Clle. 23 # 12 - 19 Sur",
        "Telefono" => "125-365-7895",
        "Fecha de Cumpleaños" => "12/10/1980",
        "Color Favorito" => "Verde"
    ),
    "persona_3" => array(
        "Nombre" => "Juana",
        "Direccion" => "Av. 34 # 16 - 12",
        "Telefono" => "326-563-7892",
        "Fecha de Cumpleaños" => "07/06/2000",
        "Color Favorito" => "Rojo"
    ),
);

$datoscolores = array(
    "Significado" => array(
        "Amarillo" => "Riqueza y alegría.",
        "Verde" => "Frescura y Salud",
        "Negro" => "Elegancia y Seriedad"
    ),
);

echo "<table BORDER>";

echo "<thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Direccion</th>
    <th>telefono</th>
    <th>Fecha de Cumpleaños</th>
    <th>Color Favorito</th>
    <th>Significado</th>
    </tr>
</thead>"; 

foreach ($datospersonas as $fila){
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($fila as $celda){
            echo "<td> $celda </td>";
            }
    echo "</tr>";
        }
echo "</table>";

?>
```

--- la idea es que en el espacio que hay en "significado" este el significado del color favorito, que esta en el otro array, pero no c como incluirlo.
--- realize este bucle para que coja el significado pero esta mal, me vota el resultado tres veces y necesito que me lo bote una vez y que lo cuadre en la tabla... ayuda ... anexo imagen de como esta en el navegador y del bucle que esta mal.

```
 foreach($datoscolores as $color => $descripcion){
    foreach($descripcion as $valor => $hola){
        if ($valor == 'Verde'){
            echo "$hola";
        }
    }
}
```

---

[image: como va quedando en el navegador]

Comment: solo tienes que anidar el bucle dentro .... tal cual lo hiciste en el ultimo.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez hola eso intento pero me ubica el resultado por fuera del cuadro y me lo imprime 3 veces

Comment: puedes agregar a la pregunta el array de significados???

Comment: <?php 
    $datoscolores = array(
        "Significado" => array(
            "Amarillo" => "Riqueza y alegría",
            "Verde" => "Frescura y Salud",
            "Negro" => "Elegancia y Seriedad"
        ),
    );
    // Muestra la descripcion del color verde:
    foreach($datoscolores as $color => $descripcion){
        foreach($descripcion as $valor => $hola){
            if ($valor == 'Verde'){
                echo "$hola";
            }
        }
    }
    ?>

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez brooo

Comment: revisa esto y me dices si soluciona tu problema... yo utilizaría el `isset` para detectar si existe la explicación del color: https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b5ia

Comment: este es el output https://i.imgur.com/pmbQ9SG.png

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez valeee, si lo soluciona, yo tenia metido en la cabeza usar si o si el foreach por algo no funcionaba muchas gracias

Comment: se usa solo si necesitas recorrerlo obligatoriamente, cuando tienes referencia de un array con otro solo es necesario validar si existe el nodo...

Comment: ya agregue la respuesta entonces saludos...

Comment: si mi solución te sirve puedes marcar la pregunta como resuelta... eso ayuda a otros a encontrarla.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez si me dio solucion y que pena por no haberlo puesto, gracias por todo bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en este caso yo utilizaría un `isset` para validar contra el array:

```
$datospersonas = array(
    "persona_1" => array(
        "Nombre" => "Camila",
        "Direccion" => "Cra. 45 # 45 - 56",
        "Telefono" => "236-598-4785",
        "Fecha de Cumpleaños" => "23/12/1997",
        "Color Favorito" => "Naranga"
    ),
    "persona_2" => array(
        "Nombre" => "Manuel",
        "Direccion" => "Clle. 23 # 12 - 19 Sur",
        "Telefono" => "125-365-7895",
        "Fecha de Cumpleaños" => "12/10/1980",
        "Color Favorito" => "Verde"
    ),
    "persona_3" => array(
        "Nombre" => "Juana",
        "Direccion" => "Av. 34 # 16 - 12",
        "Telefono" => "326-563-7892",
        "Fecha de Cumpleaños" => "07/06/2000",
        "Color Favorito" => "Rojo"
    ),
);

$datoscolores = array(
    "Significado" => array(
        "Amarillo" => "Riqueza y alegría.",
        "Verde" => "Frescura y Salud",
        "Negro" => "Elegancia y Seriedad"
    ),
);

echo "<table BORDER>";

echo "<thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Direccion</th>
    <th>telefono</th>
    <th>Fecha de Cumpleaños</th>
    <th>Color Favorito</th>
    <th>Significado</th>
    </tr>
</thead>"; 

foreach ($datospersonas as $fila){
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($fila as $key => $celda){
        if($key=='Color Favorito'){
            if(isset($datoscolores['Significado'][$celda])){
                echo "<td> $celda </td><td> ".$datoscolores['Significado'][$celda]." </td>";
            }else{
                echo "<td> $celda </td><td> Sin Significado. </td>";
            }
        }else{
            echo "<td> $celda </td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

el script puede ser optimizado:

```
$tabla ='';

foreach ($datospersonas as $fila){
        $tabla .= "<tr>";
        foreach ($fila as $key => $celda){
            if($key=='Color Favorito'){
                $tabla .= "<td> $celda </td>".(isset($datoscolores['Significado'][$celda]))?
                "<td> ".$datoscolores['Significado'][$celda]." </td>" : "<td> Sin Significado. </td>";
            }else{
                $tabla .=  "<td> $celda </td>";
            }
        }
        $tabla .=  "</tr>";
    }

echo "<table BORDER>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Direccion</th>
        <th>telefono</th>
        <th>Fecha de Cumpleaños</th>
        <th>Color Favorito</th>
        <th>Significado</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       ". $tabla."
    </tbody>
</table>";
```